# Rails 3: Adding paths in routes for new controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new controller for one of my models called Review, and named it review_controller, i put in show and update methods in it but cant get them working because rails didn't add the paths for the 2 methods.

I tried putting the follwoing in the routes file: `match "/review/update/:id", :to => "review#update"`

But it gives me a `` ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Review with ID=update):
  app/controllers/review_controller.rb:16:in `update' ``

how can i add the path to the routes file to make my update and show methods work?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a new controller in Rails 3, you can let Rails build the routes for you like this:

```
resources :review, :only => [:show, :update]
```

And then if you were to run `rake routes` in the Terminal, you'd see:

```
review GET    /review/:id(.:format)    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"review"}
PUT    /review/:id(.:format)    {:action=>"update", :controller=>"review"}
```